# Does Adobe SDK can be used to convert Word Doc into PDF without MS Office install on server machine?

Tags: c#, asp.net

Any idea about how Adobe SDK can be used to convert word doc into PDF without MS Office install on server machine?

Answer (score 0):

No, you cannot use Adobe SDK to convert Word Document to PDF.

If you want to convert Word Document to PDF without installing MS Office on the server machine, try to use [DocX](http://docx.codeplex.com/) project on CodePlex.

> [DocX](http://docx.codeplex.com/) is a .NET library that allows developers to manipulate Word 2007/2010 files, in an easy and intuitive manor. DocX is fast, lightweight and best of all it does not require Microsoft Word or Office to be installed.

[Tutorial: Converting .docx into (.doc, .pdf, .html)](http://cathalscorner.blogspot.com/2009/10/converting-docx-into-doc-pdf-html.html)

[HOW TO: Convert office documents to PDF using Open Office in C#](http://tinyway.wordpress.com/2011/03/30/how-to-convert-office-documents-to-pdf-using-open-office-in-c/)

Comment: when we talk about DocX it still required office to install on server if we want to convert word doc in to pdf
see below is note from their [link](http://cathalscorner.blogspot.com/2009/10/converting-docx-into-doc-pdf-html.html)

This code will only execute on a machine that has Microsoft’s Office installed on it. The Microsoft’s Office interop libraries actually execute a “hidden” instance of the Office. If you run the above code and then take a look at taskmgr you will see the following.

Comment: I haven't tried it but their documentation says, "DocX is fast, lightweight and best of all it does not require Microsoft Word or Office to be installed", so have you tried DocX alone?

Answer (score -1):

DocX doesn't work alone, when you try to create a PDF, in the same project page (http://cathalscorner.blogspot.com/2009/10/converting-docx-into-doc-pdf-html.html) they suggest use Interop. Your best "free" chance is using Openoffice SDK.

Comment: -1 you cannot use Office Interop in an ASP.NET page or other service  application.

Comment: ASP.NET in the Server Side, I'm using it for batch converting.

Comment: It is a horrible idea to use Office Interop from ASP.NET or another server technology. These APIs were written for use in a desktop application, for automating Office (a suite of desktop applications). Server applications are different in many ways that make it a very, very bad idea to use Office Interop in them. It's also unsupported by Microsoft, and may violate your Office license. See [Considerations for server-side Automation of Office](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/257757)